# Magento 2 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class not found

Tags: magento2, php, custom

I am using one custom php library in magento 2 to convert html to pdf. Here is the code that i am using.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList as DirectoryList;

use Company\Module\Helper\PdfCrowd;

class QuotePdf extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $_mediaDirectory;
    protected $directory_list;

    protected $dompdfFactory;
    protected $layoutFactory;

    protected $authSession;
    //protected $quote_info;
    protected $userFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->authSession->isLoggedIn()){

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            $client = new Pdfcrowd("MYUSERNAME", "xxxxxxx-KEY");

            // set HTTP response headers
            $pdf = $client->convertHtml($this->getHtmlForPdf($id));

            header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Accept-Ranges: none");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=commercialsale-".$id.".pdf");

            echo $pdf;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Helpler file

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Helper;

class PdfCrowd {
    //
    // Pdfcrowd constructor.
    // 
    // $username - your username at Pdfcrowd
    // $apikey  - your API key
    // $hostname - API hostname, defaults to pdfcrowd.com
    // 
    function __construct($username, $apikey, $hostname=null){
        if ($hostname)
            $this->hostname = $hostname;
        else
            $this->hostname = self::$api_host;
        $this->useSSL(false);
        $this->fields = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'key' => $apikey,
            'pdf_scaling_factor' => 1,
            'html_zoom' => 200);
        $this->proxy_name = null;
        $this->proxy_port = null;
        $this->proxy_username = "";
        $this->proxy_password = "";

        $this->user_agent = "pdfcrowd_php_client_".self::$client_version."_(http://pdfcrowd.com)";
    }
}
?>
```

And here is the error that i am getting...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Company\Module\Helper\PdfCrowd'
>   not found in
>   /home/patios/public_html/app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Quote/QuotePdf.php:49
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/patios/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107):
>   Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote\QuotePdf->execute() #1
>   /home/patios/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   2 /home/patios/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote\QuotePdf\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array) 3
>   /home/patios/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote\QuotePdf\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   4 /home/patios/public_html/generated/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml
>   in
>   /home/patios/public_html/app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Quote/QuotePdf.php
>   on line 49

**Note:**
This code is working on my local but not on live server.

Comment: Check exact folder and class name for Company\Module\Helper\PdfCrowd

Comment: Thanks to pointing me. Sorry actually there is capital word issue in my file name. Strange that this is working in my local.

Comment: yes, Linux is naming strict type. But other system like windows, mac not.

Answer (score 1):

Use below on your helper file:

```
class PdfCrowd extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper{
}
```

instead of

```
class PdfCrowd{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList as DirectoryList;

use Company\Module\Helper\PdfCrowd;

class QuotePdf extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $_mediaDirectory;
    protected $directory_list;

    protected $dompdfFactory;
    protected $layoutFactory;

    protected $authSession;
    //protected $quote_info;
    protected $userFactory;
    protected $_pdfCrowd;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        PdfCrowd $pdfCrowd,
        DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_pdfCrowd = $pdfCrowd;
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->authSession->isLoggedIn()){

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            $client = $this->_pdfCrowd->createPdf("MYUSERNAME", "xxxxxxx-KEY");

            // set HTTP response headers
            $pdf = $client->convertHtml($this->getHtmlForPdf($id));

            header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Accept-Ranges: none");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=commercialsale-".$id.".pdf");

            echo $pdf;
        }
    }
}
```

I have replaced method name and called with dependency injection.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Helper;

class PdfCrowd {
    //
    // Pdfcrowd constructor.
    // 
    // $username - your username at Pdfcrowd
    // $apikey  - your API key
    // $hostname - API hostname, defaults to pdfcrowd.com
    // 
    function createPdf($username, $apikey, $hostname=null){
        if ($hostname)
            $this->hostname = $hostname;
        else
            $this->hostname = self::$api_host;
        $this->useSSL(false);
        $this->fields = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'key' => $apikey,
            'pdf_scaling_factor' => 1,
            'html_zoom' => 200);
        $this->proxy_name = null;
        $this->proxy_port = null;
        $this->proxy_username = "";
        $this->proxy_password = "";

        $this->user_agent = "pdfcrowd_php_client_".self::$client_version."_(http://pdfcrowd.com)";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This error.          Class Company\Module\Helper\PdfCrowd does not exist in [Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote\QuotePdf\Interceptor]

Comment: please run this `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` then `php bin/magento cache:flush`